# Getting inconsistent row indexes using SQL CTE for table comparrison

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Sometimes the query below works and other times it doesn't return any results. The times when it doesn't return results is due to matching row numbers (rowA=rowB). Other times it does return results because the row indexes are 1 apart from one another. Any ideas what is going on here? Below is a simplified version of the query.

```
DECLARE @startRowIndex INT = 0
@param1 nvarchar(100),
@param2 nvarchar(100)

SET @startRowIndex = ( @page_index * @page_size ) + 1;

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT A.colA,
                A.colB,
                B.colC,
                ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY colA, colB) AS rn
         FROM   tableA A WITH (NOLOCK)
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB B WITH (NOLOCK)
                  ON A.colA = B.colA
                WHERE A.colD IN (@param1, @param2))
SELECT TOP (@page_size)c1.rn AS rowA,
                       c2.rn AS rowB,
                       c1.colA,
                       c1.colB,
                       c1.colC,
                       c2.colA,
                       c2.colB,
                       c2.colC
FROM   cte c1
       INNER JOIN cte c2
         ON c1.colA = c2.colA
            AND c2.rn = c1.rn + 1
            AND c1.rn >= @startRowIndex
            AND ( c1.colB <> c2.colB
                   OR c1.colC <> c2.colC )
ORDER  BY c1.colA,
          c1.colB
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking but (1) If you care about consistency why are you using `NOLOCK`? (2) Is `ColA, ColB` unique?

Answer (score 1):

Just focusing on the outer query:

```
SELECT top (@page_size)c1.rn as rowA, c2.rn as rowB, c1.colA, c1.colB, c1.colC, c2.colA, c2.colB, c2.colC
FROM cte c1 INNER JOIN
     cte c2
     ON c1.colA = c2.colA AND c2.rn = c1.rn + 1 AND
------------------------------^
        c1.rn >= @startRowIndex AND
        (c1.colB <> c2.colB OR c1.colC <> c2.colC)
order by c1.colA, c1.colB
```

The noted condition is going to fail on the last row for every `colA` value in the CTE.  So, if you only have singleton values (perhaps due to the other conditions), you will not get any results.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, the thing I am noticing is that sometimes it doesn't return results and other times it does. I guess the c1.rn and c2.rn values aren't always in sync in the same way. For instance, the first row returned might have rowA=154, rowB=155. Other times it will have rowA=154, rowB=154, and other times it will have rowA=155, rowB=154, etc...I'm trying to figure out if there is any way around this, or if I need to redesign.

Comment: @flerngobot . . . I would go for re-design.  I'm guessing there is a simpler way to achieve what this query is doing.

Comment: Basically I am trying to just get one set of rows where the rows are different in the table. This query is returning them in pairs, and I can't figure out a way to consistently get just one set of rows.

Comment: @flerngobot . . . You should ask another question, along with sample data and desired results.